# How to determine the distribution of $U:=(X,Y,Z)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I've got a question concerning the distribution of a multi dimensional random variable.

> > I know that $X$ and $Y$ and $Z$ are each normal distributed with certain expectations and variances. How can I then determine the distribution of $U:=(X,Y,Z)$ if I do not certainly know that $X,Y$ and $Z$ are independent?

I know in case that $X,Y$ and $Z$ were independent I could easily find the multivariate distribution by multiplicating the densities $f_X$, $f_Y$ and $f_Z$.

But, as I said, $X,Y$ and $Z$ do not have to be independent. What can I do then?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are not independent, this means that the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is not diagonal.

The covariance matrix in your case is defined as follows:

$$\Sigma = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)^2] & \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)] & \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)(Z-\mu_Z)]\\
\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mu_Y)(X-\mu_X)] & \mathbb{E}[(Y-\mu_Y)^2] & \mathbb{E}[(Y-\mu_Y)(Z-\mu_Z)]\\
\mathbb{E}[(Z-\mu_Z)(X-\mu_X)] & \mathbb{E}[(Z-\mu_Z)(Y-\mu_Y)] & \mathbb{E}[(Z-\mu_Z)^2]\end{array} \right]$$

where $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu_X$, $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mu_Y$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z] = \mu_Z$.

If you have the covariance matrix, then you can use the general formula you find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Non-degenerate_case) in order to obtain the joint distribution you are looking for!

Comment: In case the covariance matrix is diagonal, then does that mean that $X,Y$ and $Z$ are independent? But only if I assume that $U$ is multivariate normal distributed, right? But how do I know that because I have to find the multivariate distribution and cannot assume its multivariate normal distributed?

Comment: You can have dependency if the distribution of one variable depends from the other. Is this the case? For example, $f_X$ depends on $X$ and also on $Y$.

Comment: In my case the covariance matrix is indeed diagonal. But I do not know if from this it follows that $X, Y$ and $Z$ are independent, because to my knowledge it only follows independence if one assumes that $U$ is multivariate normal distributed.

Comment: Look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Expectation_and_covariance

Comment: @mathfemi Good point, this answer requires that (X,Y,Z) is **jointly** normal (note that, otherwise, not much can be said).